# Flash to Objective C: Best way to make a blend layer multiply

Tags: objective-c, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, ipad

I don't work in Objective C but a question came up today for me on a flash site I am developing that someone is developing for the Ipad in tandem.  I created some previews of products that have image overlays on them. The overlays, in flash, are basically a layered file with the product on the first layer, an image on the second with the layer set to blend:Multiply, and some masks on the third.

So my question is, how would you do this in Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at UIImage's [`– drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/drawAtPoint%3ablendMode%3aalpha%3a).